# Security In Cron Job triggered scripts in PHP & Codeigniter

Tags: php, linux, cron, codeigniter-3

First thing i want to mention is i am relatively fresher in developing, I am working on a codeigniter project, In that project I need to inform users of that application about expiry of their service a week before via email also i need to change database status after expiry date passes for a service

To accomplish that i am developing scripts that can be triggered via CRON JOBS in cpanel, Well my question is can we provide any level of security for cron jobs triggered PHP Scripts like we do in a php application where we check the user role before access to each class or script, My concern is that the scripts will be accessible via URL and anybody knowing those URL's can trigger it.

Example of URL of PHP Script that will be triggered by cron job schedules.

> www.example.com/admin/remainder_emails

can i anyhow provide any level of authentication via PHP or Linux to PHP scripts that only authorised user can trigger it, i want to know this not just for this application but for my future projects too. I would be grateful if someone can just list me out the basic security issues to keep in mind using cron job triggered scripts in application.

Comment: Scripts executed by CRON must be outside the document root of your vhost so they are not accessible at all via web but CRON can run them.

Comment: @marekful .. thanks for advice but my project is in codeignitor , how can i run a script written in codeignitor outside document root where the codeignitor installation is.